# How to control iPhone System volume?

Tags: swift, media-player, ios11, avkit, mpvolumeview

I am trying to control iPhone System volume from my iOS App using Swift. I am following this below link but I can't do it.

https://github.com/ioscreator/ioscreator/tree/master/IOS8SwiftVolumeTutorial/IOS8SwiftVolumeTutorial

After using this I am able to change the volume control of custom audio file and I can also control the volume of other applications such as Youtube. But I can't control iOS Clock App's alarm volume and ringtone volume. How can I control all kinds of system volume including alarm and ringtone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to do this on iOS. You generally do not have control over a lot of things outside of your app. Ringtone and alarm volume is one of the things you cannot control.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @Rengers